# value is not selected in angularjs with chosen directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am creating a project using angularjs. I want to show the selected value.I am using the chosen filter from:

https://github.com/leocaseiro/angular-chosen

Here is my code:

```
.directive('chooseCustomer', function($timeout) {

  var linker = function(scope, element, attr) {

    scope.$watch('customerInfo', function() {
      $timeout(function() {
        element.trigger('chosen:updated');
      }, 0, false);
    }, true);

    $timeout(function() {
      element.chosen();
    }, 0, false);
  };

  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: linker
  };
})
```

In controller:

```
$scope.assCustmoers.customerName = companyName //here is compony name show
```

In html:

```
  <select class="selectbox_menulist" required  name="customerName" choose-customer = ""   ng-options="customer['company-name'] for customer in customerInfo" ng-model="assCustmoers.customerName" ng-change="getBillingNumber()" ng-disabled="promoAsscoiation" data-placeholder="Please Select">
```

Comment: do you want to show the selected value in the select box ?

Comment: Yes..................

Comment: Why dont you use ng-selected ?

Comment: @Karan selected value is stored in assCustmoers.customerName as it is double binded with select tag... access that value inside getBillingNumber() function and do further processing of that value in that function.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem with the model, model value is not updated

```
.directive('chooseCustomer', function($timeout) {

  var linker = function(scope, element, attr) {
 scope.$watch('assCustmoers.customerName', function() {
      $timeout(function() {
        element.trigger('chosen:updated');
      }, 0, false);
    }, true);
    scope.$watch('customerInfo', function() {
      $timeout(function() {
        element.trigger('chosen:updated');
      }, 0, false);
    }, true);

    $timeout(function() {
      element.chosen();
    }, 0, false);
  };

  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: linker
  };
})
```

Comment: That's @Ajay answers